# Overriding prestashop module translation missing

Tags: module, translation, prestashop, overriding

I try to modify a module template in prestashop so I've copied the module to my theme folder "modules". 
I've noticed that the theme is changing the only problem is that the translation is not. I got the original text on the final shop template. Is there some simple way of making this work?
I don't know how to make modules so this way was great except the translation part - the rest of the store is translated except those modules. I use prestashop 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

In your Back Office, you need to edit the Module Translations under Tools > Translations > Modify Translations. They are translated separately from the Front Office and Back Office translations, just select "Modules" from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your module can be translated also : 
    {l s='Login' mod='blockuserinfo'}

The name of the module has to be here,
also make sure to check the prestashop user guide : 
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Translations+in+PrestaShop+1.5